# DRF serializer remove imagefield absolute url

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In DRF, now if i save the image the `serializer` is giving me the image with absolute path. But in my scenario, i don't want absolute path. I just need a image path which is there in DB. In my scenario, i'm hard-coding the image path in json. So i can't use the absolute path. Can anyone suggest some ideas to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above answers are working for list and retrieve method, but i need to add for post and retrieve instead of querying and serializing it again. Below method will work.

Normally for **ImageField** and **FileField** will return name but in DRF it's been converted to url for usefulness. So u just need to change there that's it.

In your serailizer, just specify below like that:

```
Field_name = serializers.ImageField(use_url=False)
```

So this line will convert absolute url to name as response after **Save** and **Update**.

For further reference refer this [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#imagefield)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SerializerMethodField`. You can return the value as it is stored in the database by doing the following:

```py
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_image(self, obj):
        return obj.image.file.name
```

docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Comment: This i can use for Listing, but save and update response it won't work. I need to write custom serializer for that too. Is there any other solutions is there

Comment: If you don't want to use the features of FileField provided by Django, why not just use CharField in your Model? Or you can do this by specifying CharField only in the Serializer. Since FileField inherits CharField, there should be no problem with saving and loading.
`image = serializers.CharField()`

Answer (score 1):

Create custom **`FileField`** will solve the issue

```
class CustomFileField(serializers.FileField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        if not value:
            return None

        if not getattr(value, 'path', None):
            # If the file has not been saved it may not have a path.
            return None
        return value.path


class MyFooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    my_file_field = CustomFileField()
    ...
    # other code
```